# Creating an html code responsive email in Outlook 365

Tags: outlook, responsive-design, office365, html-email, responsive-emails

I have created a single column responsive HTML email that I am able to send through Outlook 365. However, I am having trouble with multi-column layouts that are supposed to flow into a single column on mobile devices. While testing the code on email client test services, it appears to work, but when I try to send it through Outlook to different email clients, the multi-column layout does not work. Unfortunately, I cannot use a third-party mass email service and must send the emails through Outlook. Is it even possible to create a multi-column responsive email that works when sent with Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

No.

The normal technique of using `display:inline-block` and max-widths, and media queries if necessary are not possible. This is because Outlook is interpreting the code within their print-based Microsoft Word rendering engine. It will remove all that, and this is why you normally use an ESP like MailChimp or whatnot to send them.

Abnormal techniques like the Fab Four by Remi Parmentier also won't work because Outlook will strip some necessary parts before sending.

Outlook also converts everything to a strict pixel-perfect (inch-perfect, even) design. So even percentages don't work, I'm pretty sure.